# @types/angular-resource takes old version of @types/angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript, npm, dependencies

In my package.json I have these entries among others:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@types/angular": "1.6.56",
        "@types/angular-resource": "1.5.15"
...
```

And in node_modules/@types/angular-resource/node_modules/@types/angular/package.json this:

```
    "name": "@types/angular",
    "version": "1.6.55"
```

So there is a mismatch between those versions?
angular-resource has this as dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@types/angular": "*"
    }
```

So it matches every version. But why does it takes 1.6.55 when I specified 1.6.56?

I'm not sure if that is the root cause of my problem when running tsc:

```
error TS2694: Namespace 'angular' has no exported member 'resource'.
```

And if so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to delete the node_modules folder and manually add the dependencies again with npm add/install, and suddenly v 1.6.55 was gone. Just removing the node_modules folder and/or yarn.lock was not enough.